# How can I change view in Fragment which is contained ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`. And ViewPager is consisted with 4 fragments(for example, I'll call the fragments' name 1, 2, 3, 4). My 2(second fragment) has a `ListView`, and if I click a list-item, the 2(second fragment) will be changed another view. At that time, another view is not 1, 3 or 4. `That is a new view`.

It is purpose to make board's `category`(like, sports-soccer-midfielder). So when I select sport item, the view will show another list-item(like, soccer, baseball, basketball an so on). The category will be consisted with 3 step. So i will prepare second and third view of 2(second fragment).
But I don't know how to change view or fragment. I found some clue to solve this problem in google.

That is

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fmt = fm.beginTransaction();
View2 v2 = new View2(); // View2 is another view
fmt.replace(R.id.view1, v2);
fmt.commit();
```

I used that code and it succeed to change view. But only a part of view is changed. What is the problem? How can I solve that?

Here is Pic of second fragment

[image]

and this is a view when I click list-item. only a part of view is changed.

[image]

(I can't attach picture directly, so someone help please ^^ )

And this is my code of second fragment.

```
public class MatchingFragment extends Fragment {

    View2 v2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.matching_fragment, container, false);

        final MatchingListViewAdapter adapter = new MatchingListViewAdapter();

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.matching_list1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.lock), "LOCK", "This is lock icon");
        adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.setup), "SETUP", "This is setup icon");
        adapter.addItem(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.user), "USER", "This is user icon");

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fmt = fm.beginTransaction();
                v2 = new View2();
                fmt.replace(R.id.view1, v2);
                fmt.commit();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Sagar Zala thx ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start a activity when you click item on listview. because if you replace new fragment with viewpager how can you go back to previous fragment. and why you create View2() object, what is the purpose of that?

if you want to replace fragment with viewpager use this code for it, don't replace viewpager by viewpager

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentOne();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.view, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: that view is not completed view. I will make button which can ho back to previous view. and your code operate same with my picture.